# Bitcoin config file to setup bitcoin node in testnet network in ubuntu

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, testnet

I am new to blockchain, I want to setup my node in testnet network in my ubuntu machine.

I am using this below mentioned bitcoin.conf file. Is this the correct format to sync the node faster?  Or I need to do the changes in this config file.

```
testnet=1
dnsseed=0
upnp=0
setgenerate=1
blocksonly=1

port=12000
rpcport=5000

server=1
prune=1000

rpcallowip=0.0.0.0/0

rpcuser=someuser
rpcpassword=somepass
```

I am referring this link to setup my bitcoin node https://www.codeooze.com/blockchain/bitcoind-running-in-docker/

Comment: I have started the node sync:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sync faster I have updated my bitcoin.conf file by adding the node addresses.
My latest config file is similar to this:

```
testnet=1
regtest=0
dnsseed=0
upnp=0
setgenerate=1
blocksonly=1

server=1

addnode=104.237.131.138
addnode=151.80.205.132
addnode=192.155.82.123
addnode=74.220.255.190
addnode=80.100.203.151

maxconnections=15
minrelaytxfee=0.0001
maxmempool=200
maxreceiverbuffer=2500
maxsendbuffer=500
dbcache=16000

rpcallowip=0.0.0.0/0
rpcuser=someuser
rpcpassword=somepass
```

Comment: remember when using testnet rpc config needs to go under [test] section.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you can use [Lopp's Bitcoin Core config file generator](https://jlopp.github.io/bitcoin-core-config-generator/) to set up your Bitcoin Core config files. Parameters are collected in groups by topic (e.g: Mining, Networking, ...). Moreover, each parameter contains a description of what it is used for and what is it's default value.

Answer (score 2):

Meanwhile...

addnode needs to be in the [test] section for testnet. So it's

```
[test]
addnode=104.237.131.138
addnode=151.80.205.132
addnode=192.155.82.123
addnode=74.220.255.190
addnode=80.100.203.151
```

now.

Answer (score 1):

To sync faster your config should be like that:

```
testnet=1
blocksonly=1
rpcport=5000
server=1
listen=0
prune=1000 # this has no effect during syncing 
dbcache=16000 # will take too much memory
rpcallowip=0.0.0.0/0
rpcuser=someuser
rpcpassword=somepass
```

Comment: Thanks @Adam, I will try this.  And I want to know should we use rpcallowip=0.0.0.0/0 or we can remove from the config file because this is 0 only?

Comment: If you want to use RPC remotely you should set here your IP range or 0.0.0.0/0 for any IP.